# JSON returns excessive information

Tags: php, json, database, laravel

I am using Laravel.

I don't no how to explain very well... The problem is that I am trying to get some values from my database.

Route:

```
Route::post('inbox/all', 'InboxController@message_type_1');
```

My controller:

```
public function message_type_1(Request $request)
{
  $user_id =  Auth::user()->id;
  $result =   Messages::where('receiver_id', $user_id)->with('sender')->with(['bookings' => function($query) {
    $query->with('currency');
  }])->with('object_address')->orderBy('id','desc');

  $result =  $result->paginate(10)->toJson();
  return $result;
}
```

The return gives me alot of information, and some i don't wan't

This is the response:

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [{
    "id": 2,
    "object_id": 3,
    "booking_id": 1,
    "sender_id": 1,
    "receiver_id": 2,
    "message": "It is accepted",
    "type_id": 5,
    "read": 1,
    "archive": 0,
    "star": 0,
    "created_at": "2019-02-26 11:45:28",
    "updated_at": "2019-02-26 12:15:11",
    "created_time": "26\/02\/2019",
    "host_user": 0,
    "guest_user": 1,
    "sender": {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Joe",
      "last_name": "Cos",
      "email": "email-91@hotmail.com",
      "profile_image": null,
      "balance": 0,
      "status": "Active",
      "created_at": "2019-02-21 15:19:26",
      "updated_at": "2019-02-21 15:19:26",
      "profile_src": "http:\/\/xxx.com\/public\/images\/user_pic-225x225.png"
    },
    "bookings": {
      "id": 1,
      "object_id": 3,
      "code": "mYuL4p",
      "host_id": 1,
      "user_id": 2,
      "start_date": "2019-02-26",
      "end_date": "2019-02-27",
      "status": "Accepted",
      "guest": 0,
      "total_night": 1,
      "per_night": 20,
      "base_price": 20,
      "cleaning_charge": 0,
      "guest_charge": 0,
      "service_charge": 0,
      "security_money": 0,
      "host_fee": 0,
      "total": 20,
      "booking_type": "request",
      "currency_code": "EUR",
      "cancellation": "Flexible",
      "transaction_id": "67427302T32774838",
      "payment_method_id": 1,
      "accepted_at": "2019-02-26 11:45:28",
      "expired_at": null,
      "declined_at": null,
      "cancelled_at": null,
      "cancelled_by": null,
      "created_at": "2019-02-26 11:37:36",
      "updated_at": "2019-02-26 11:45:28",
      "host_payout": 23,
      "label_color": "success",
      "date_range": "Feb 26 - 27, 2019",
      "expiration_time": "2019\/02\/27 11:37:36",
      "currency": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Europe",
        "code": "EUR",
        "symbol": "&euro;",
        "rate": "0.88",
        "status": "Active",
        "default": "0",
        "org_symbol": "&euro;"
      }
    },
    "object_address": {
      "id": 3,
      "object_id": 3,
      "address_line_1": "XXXXXXXXX, 4050-352 Porto, Portugal",
      "address_line_2": null,
      "latitude": "49.999",
      "longitude": "-8.88810419921",
      "city": "P",
      "state": "P",
      "country": "P",
      "postal_code": "4050-352"
    }
  }],
  "from": 1,
  "last_page": 1,
  "next_page_url": null,
  "per_page": 10,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": 1,
  "total": 1
}
```

Why I am getting so many information?? How to control this madness?

Comment: To help understand your question you should also explain what information you were expecting to see. Also, it is spelled JSON (not JASON).

Comment: You're not filtering it. I think there's a PHP function for that.

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a way to "hide" different attributes from JSON

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

on each model in your application, you can specify `$hidden` attribute with array of the properties that you want to hide from the JSON object.

So for your example, you could do something like this in your model

```
<?php
...
class Messages extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = [
        "object_id",
        "booking_id",
        "sender_id",
        "receiver_id",
        // add more columns you wish to hide
    ]; 
}
```

alternatively, there is also $visible attribute that works the opposite way, i.e. you define only the fields that should be visible in JSON object

```
<?php
...
class Messages extends Model
{
    protected $visible = [
        "id",
        "name",
        // add more columns you wish to show
    ]; 
}
```

Comment: What version of laravel are you using ?

There is also an alternative to this, using `protected $visible = [...]`, that works the opposite way - here you should only list the attributes that you actually want to display

Comment: The version is 5.4.36

Comment: I updated the original answer, I would try the visible alternative as well. THis should be docs link specific for your laravel version
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Comment: I will try explain my code does 2 levels of querys 1 get's the message id and the users id and after this the 2 level query get all the user information! i don't no why i get all the user information when i just need names (for exemple)! In the model of the users if i use the  protected $hidden['email'] it works! But now i have a problem becuase it works and does what i want, but in the other hand i also have json code in other page that need that info and the  protected $hidden blocks the information!

Comment: in that case (if you need same model with different attributes in different places), it is probably better to use the solution @apokryfos suggested yesterday - use Laravel Resources https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources You might be able to achieve the same result hiding and showing attributes during call time, but resources were specifically made for the purpose you need

Comment: it is for 5.7!  5.4 dosen't have eloquent-resources but thanks again 
I do not know how to thank the help

Comment: you are right, sorry, resources came along in 5.5. All I can think of rn is to actually code some cleaning algorithm yourself - i.e. convert $result =  $result->paginate(10)->toArray();, looping through the array and clean up it manually. But it would be pretty inefficient. Maybe a better option would be to upgrade to Laravel 5.5 (5.4 does not get security updates anymore) and use resources for that